# SyntaxError in finally (Django)

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django, and I have the following error:

> Exception Type:   SyntaxError
>   Exception Value:  invalid syntax (views.py, **line 115**)

My viws.py code looks like this:

```
def myview(request):
try:
    [...]
except MyExceptionClass, e:
    [...]
finally:
    render_to_response('template.html', {}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Where MyExceptionClass is a class extending Exception, and **line 115** is the 'finally' clause line. If I remove finally clause, (lines 115-116), works fine. Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What version of python are you using? Prior to 2.5 you can't have both an except clause and a finally clause in the same try block.

You can work around this by nesting try blocks.

```
def myview(request):
    try:
        try:
            [...]
        except MyExceptionClass, e:
            [...]
    finally:
        render_to_response(
            'template.html', {}, context_instance = RequestContext(request)
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

Nadia is right, so if you're stuck with Python 2.4 or earlier, use *two* try blocks:

```
try:
  try:
        [...]
  except MyExceptionClass, e:
        [...]
finally:
        render_to_response(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, should be:

```
except MyExceptionClass as e:
    [....]
```

In your case, this is not the case.

Comment: Only in Python 3 -- in 2.5, the original poster's syntax is right.